# Javascript/Jquery code runs once on first event, twice on second, and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2

I have this JS function tied to an HTML button `onclick` attribute:

```
function AddFbLikes() {
$('#fbform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
    $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(idx, val){
        callResult(val.value);
    });
})}
```

Assuming I have 4 `input` elements matching the criteria, I will get 4 elements appended to my HTML (that's what `callResult()` does). But If I click the button a second time, I will get 8 more, and if I click it 3 times I'll get 12 more..

I've tried debugging this but can't figure it out. I'm coming from Python/Django so there must be something I'm not getting with Javascript.

Comment: What other code is used to call the AddFbLikes function?

Comment: @jeff none at all. Not in Javascript or Python. I will add the HTML which contains the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `AddFbLikes` adds another event listener every time it's called, for every element found by `$('#fbform')`.  That's why it starts with four for the four elements it finds, then grows by four each time.  There are probably better ways to structure your code, but considering what you've given us, try `one` instead of `on` (http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
function AddFbLikes() {
    $('#fbform').one('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
        $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(idx, val){
            callResult(val.value);
        });
    }
)}
```

Comment: Ok. A few runs show that this works perfectly. Thank you George. I will upvote and probably mark this as the correct answer unless something better comes along (not that I would know!). Can you maybe elaborate on why you wrote my code could be better structured? and more importantly explain why/how addFbLikes is "adding" another event listener, and what's the implications of that? why does another listener trigger stuff twice?

Comment: Well I would say somewhere outside of `AddFbLikes` is where your should be calling `$('#fbform').on('submit', function(e) {`, somewhere that gets called once and only once, instead of over and over.  Also besides the documentation for `one` I already linked to check out http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: To further answer, an element can have any number of listeners, be they identical or otherwise.  In your case each time `AddFbLikes` was being called, it was adding another event listener to each element found.

Comment: Is that event listener the function I’m passing as the second parameter?

Comment: Yes, the second parameter, the one after the first parameter the event name `submit`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be binding an event handler when the user clicks on the button. That adds an additional handler each time, and they all cascade when the event occurs. Just check the boxes.

```
function AddFbLikes() {
    $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(idx, val){
        callResult(val.value);
    });
}
```

To prevent the form from being submitted when you click the button, change it to `type="button"` (the default is `type="submit"`).

```
<button type="button" id="submit_facebook" onclick="AddFbLikes()" class="btn-primary img-rounded">add selected artists</button>
```

In general, it's rarely right to bind one event handler inside another. Even if the second event handler should be conditional on the first event having happened, a better way to deal with that is to have the first event handler set a variable that the second handler checks.

Comment: Quite possibly a better answer than mine, though mine does explain the behavior the OP was seeing.  I just saw `on` inside a function call and looked no further, knowing `one` would solve it.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. I understand your answer, but one thing I don’t get is: where am I binding one event handler inside another? I understand why calling ‘on’ multiple times will attach multiple handlers, but where am I doing binding inside of binding?

Comment: A function called from `onclick` is an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get rid of your inline javascript on the button and go unobtrusive all the way. This will ensure that the form submit handler is only added once.

```
$('#submit_facebook').on('click', function( { 
     //Attach the handler for form submit
     $('#fbform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
        $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(idx, val){
             callResult(val.value);
        });
     })}    
    //Detatch the event handler for the button click   
    $('#submit_facebook').off('click'); 
});
```

Button HTML is now:

```
<button id="submit_facebook" class="btn-primary img-rounded">add selected artists</button>
```

Comment: I agree and have up-voted but I think to expand on this you might consider mentioning where the above block can be placed (after the html, in a `document.ready` block, etc.)  The OP is not especially jQuery savvy (though Django is a Python web framework)